Simple React.js Image not displaying
I am starting to learn React.JS and I want to display a image...
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
const root =createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <main>
    <img src="react_new.png" width="40px" height="30px"/>
 
  </main>
)


I see a empty image box but not the image. Image is also in the same pathway as main.js. I tried changing the width,height and loaction of the image but doesnt seems to work at all. All i get is a empty image box.
Can you guys help me? Thanks...

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example using https://stackblitz.com/

Your image should be in public folder of your project


First you should put the image in public folder as it's the best place to keep static assets that you want to reference directly.
Update the image source - when you place the image in public folder , you can reference it with absolute path that is starting with /.
<img src="/react_new.png" width="40px" height="30px" />
If you are having image in src folder instead of public folder then you can import it explicitly.
explicit import :
import ReactNewImage from './react_new.png';

<img src={ReactNewImage} width="40px" height="30px" />

Why would he want to put the image in a public folder instead of referencing it from where it is? If it is located alongside the component, why would he want to put it elsewhere?
